How do I adjust the formula that imagemagick uses to evaluate sequence mean?
I have this chaotic pendulum that I built and painted with orange stripes.
I took a slow-motion video (for the high fps) with my Android camera of it swinging (I don't have a nice camera) on a tripod, and I am trying to use imagemagick to combine all the frames into something that shows the interesting pattern the orange stripes create together with the black.
The result that I end up with when I use:
convert $(ls frames/*.png | head -n 5000) -evaluate-sequence min sequence_min.png

is close to what I want, but black dominates the image where I'd rather be able to see the orange stripes over top. The edges of the pattern here are what I'm looking for, but it should be the entire thing not just the edge.

I got the result I wanted before I painted the pendulum, just using a strip of red tape, but now that there's black, evaluate-sequence min doesn't work. What command or method should I use to show this pattern best?


Probably the -compose option and probably -compose lighten. But it would be much better to reshoot the thing with a dark background. Gimp/Photoshop have a similar layer blend options, if you want to be a bit more "manual".

Hmm, none of the -compose commands worked for this. There's not a way to prioritize orange?
